# How is the third line of code here creating a reverse array?

Tags: javascript

This function should be taking an array and reversing its order. It works but I don't understand what the third line "for (let i = arr.length..." is doing. Can someone please explain what is being pushed to the new reversed array?

```
const reverseArray = arr => {
    let reversed = [];
    for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        reversed.push(arr[i]);
    }
    return reversed
}
```

Comment: it loop the array in reverse directions going from the last position of the array to the first one

Comment: Perhaps visiting [manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) is in order

Comment: That for loop simply goes over the array elements in reverse order - it starts at `arr.length - 1`, and iterates until `i` has become 0. And because these items, that are getting iterated over in reverse order, are then pushed into a new array, the result in that new array _is_ the reverse of the original array.

Comment: 3rd line is initializing the `i` variable with the length of the `arr` parameter. By doing `-1` from length it sets the index value of the last element of the array.

Comment: This would have been easy to debug yourself. Just log `i` to see what it is on each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the line:

```
for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

The for loop is starting at the last element, and looping through each until it gets to the end element.
Each time it is then appending the array item to the reversed array.

As an example with an array:

```
Index Value
0     10
1     20
2     30
3     40
```

The first part of the for loop

```
let i = arr.length - 1
```

Sets i to arr.length - 1 = 4 - 1 = 3

So the first value added would be arr[3] = 40

Each iteration of the loop (while i is >- 0) assigns the current indexed i value and decrements i by 1.

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to Javascript or programming in general, check this cool website: [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp)

What the 3rd line does is to go from the last element of an array (hence the arr.length - 1, the -1 is because array positions start on 0 not 1) to the first one, it pushes each value to a new array (reversed) and that's how you get the final result.

Answer (score 0):

It takes everything in the array supplied (`arr`), starts at the last element and pushes those elements back to front into a new array (`reversed`). Reversing the items in the array.

---

so if you have `["apple", "banana", "pear"]` it will start at the last element (`pear`) push that to a new array. Then move on to the element before `pear` (`banana`). Until there are no more items in the old array.

So the new array wil contain `["pear", "banana", "apple"]`

---

There's multiple ways to do this, perhaps checking out [this link](https://www.techiedelight.com/loop-through-array-backwards-javascript/) helps you in understanding.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ex - arr[a,b,c,d,e,f,g]
          0 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

this loop is currently worked as reverse like (6,5,4,3,2,1,0) because it's consist i--

```
for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    reversed.push(arr[i]);
}
```

when loop runs the last element of arr array in insert first of reversed array